# Symfony2 > Easier way to determine access

Tags: php, symfony

I am busy writing an API in Symfony2. One of the API functions is to return all the users (not uncommon). Obviously before I return a list of users I must ensure that a user is logged in and has at least ROLE_ADMIN before returning the users. Currently I am doing it like this:

```
public function getAllUsersAction()
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    if ($user == null) die("Unauthorized");
    $userRoles = $user->getRoles();
    $bAuthorized = false;
    foreach ($userRoles as $userRole)
        if ($userRole->getRole() == "ROLE_ADMIN" || $userRole->getRole() == "ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN")
            $bAuthorized = true;
    if ($bAuthorized) return createJsonResponse($this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('PmbLicensingBundle:User')->findAll());
    else die("Unauthorized");
}
```

My question is simply whether there is an easier way in Symfony to determine whether a user is logged in and has ROLE_ADMIN than the process that I am taking, as it seems to be quite lumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
if (!$this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) die('Nope Nope Nope');
```

Or of course you can follow @artworkad's advice and setup a firewall which would prevent the action from ever being called in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The authentication logic does not belong into the controller's action. Your software has to check if the user is logged in before the action is accessed redirecting the response if authentication fails or the given roles are not sufficient.

[**FosUserBundle**](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) is a great tool that does a lot of security and authentication for you. On SO there are already answers how to configure FosUserBundle to work with REST e.g.

[How to restfully login, Symfony2 Security, FOSUserBundle, FOSRestBundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672169/how-to-restfully-login-symfony2-security-fosuserbundle-fosrestbundle)