# Symfony log into by using FosRestBundle

Tags: rest, symfony, authentication

I'm working on a API. To give User Access - for example by smartphone - I need to login users by rest.

Is there an existing module available? Actually, I'm using fosUserBundle. Maybe there is a possibility to get those two bundle work together?

The Users which will login by rest are already existing as "normal" fos users.

It would be grest if you could gomme some links, tips or hints cause I'm searching and searching and searching and for the reason that I am new in symfony it's not that easy :):)

rgrds

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to restfully login, Symfony2 Security, FOSUserBundle, FOSRestBundle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672169/how-to-restfully-login-symfony2-security-fosuserbundle-fosrestbundle)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use FOSUserBundle for login since a smartphone by the API.

**APIBundle/Controller/UserController.php** (the default route is /api)

```
   /** 
   * @Post("/user/login") 
   * @Template(engine="serializer") 
   */ 
   public function loginAction() 
   { 
     $request      = $this->get('request'); 

     $username = $request->request->get('username'); 
     $password = $request->request->get('password'); 

     return $this->container->get('myproject_user.user_service') 
                            ->login($username, $password); 
   }
```

in this method, I call a personal service who manage the user's functions. (UserHandler.php)

**UserBundle/Handler/UserHandler.php**

```
        class UserHandler implements UserHandlerInterface
        {
          private $om;
          private $entityClass;
          private $repository;
          private $container;
          private $manager;

          public function   __construct(ObjectManager $om, Container $container, $entityClass)
          {
            $this->om = $om;
            $this->entityClass = $entityClass;
            $this->repository = $this->om->getRepository($this->entityClass);
            $this->container = $container;
            $this->manager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
          }

          public function   login($username, $password)
          {
             $jsonErrorCreator = $this->container->get('myproject_api.create_error_json');
             $code = 0;

             // check the arguments here.          

             $user = $this->manager->findUserByUsername($username);

             if($user === null) $user = $this->manager->findUserByEmail($username);

             if($user === null)
             {
               $code = 224;
               return ($jsonErrorCreator->createErrorJson($code, $username));            
             }

             // check the user password      
             if($this->checkUserPassword($user, $password) === false)
             {                   
               $code = 225;
               return ($jsonErrorCreator->createErrorJson($code, null));
             }

             // log the user
             $this->loginUser($user);

             $jsonCreator = $this->container->get('myproject_api.create_json');
             $response = $jsonCreator->createJson(array('success'=>true, 'user'=>$user));
             return $response;
          }

          protected function    loginUser(User $user)
          {       
            $security = $this->container->get('security.context');                                 
            $providerKey = $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.firewall_name');    
            $roles = $user->getRoles();
            $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, $providerKey, $roles);      
            $security->setToken($token);                                                
          }

  protected function    checkUserPassword(User $user, $password)                         
  {       
    $factory = $this->container->get('security.encoder_factory');                          
    $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($user);                                     

    if(!$encoder)                                                              
      return false;

    return $encoder->isPasswordValid($user->getPassword(), $password, $user->getSalt());
  }

}
```

**UserBundle/Handler/UserHandlerInterface.php**

```
Interface UserHandlerInterface
{
  public function login($username, $password);
}
```

Don't forget to declare your service !

**UserBundle/Resources/config/services.yml**

```
myproject_user.user_service: 
    class: %myproject_user.user_handler.class% 
    arguments: [ @doctrine.orm.entity_manager, @service_container, %fos_user.model.user.class%]
```

You can now login with your smartphone at the adresse api/user/login

Comment: Hey Gura, thank you for taking your time to help  me :) This sounds very good. Can you post the complete files with all use cases? This would help me getting the contex informations between all files.

Comment: NP @TheTom. For the login, you just need these functions. Concening my project architecture, I do this for my own project [tuto link](http://welcometothebundle.com/symfony2-rest-api-the-best-2013-way/). The github with all source files here [github](https://github.com/liuggio/symfony2-rest-api-the-best-2013-way).

Comment: Hi Gura, I'm checkin it at the moment :):) For the reason that i'm a noob :) It is a bit confusing but I think I will get it some how :)

Comment: If I use thsi code from you loginAction, 
* @Template(engine="serializer"), I get an 2/2 FileLoaderLoadException: Cannot import resource. he annotation "@Template" in method  was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?

Comment: This is nice but I'm wondering about brute force attacks. This code doesn't seem to provide such protection, or maybe Symfony is doing that on its own ?

Answer (score 1):

I think I got the solution:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html

This seems pretty nice to me and paired with Guras inputit should work as well.