# Communication between mobile phone application and server

Tags: web-services, symfony, mobile, fosuserbundle

I have a backend server in which is developed using Symfony 2 framework and FOSUserBundle as authentication provider.
I have made a custom (simple controller that return JSON) API to handle communication between server and the mobile app.

So basically all methods in this API need an authenticated user.

Blow is a little discussion between the server and the mobile app of what I’m planning to do :

1. mobile app: send https request with parameters(email and password)
2. server: verify email & password, generate a token, store it in the user table and send it to the mobile app
3. mobile app : include the token in future requests
4. server:  getUserByToken() and continue the rest of logic

My Questions:

1. How to achieve credential(email & pass) verification on the server using FOSUserBundle (or anything else)?
2. I’m wondering what if a hacker use the Man In The Middle technic, get the token and use it to send requests to the server?

Disclaimer : I’m very novice in security and intermediate Symfony 2.
I’m sorry for not including image which will explain more(I haven’t enough reputation).

Answer (score 0):

> 1.How to achieve credential(email & pass) verification on the server using FOSUserBundle (or anything else)?

Symfony2 handle it for you. You have an example of login [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25872305/symfony-log-into-by-using-fosrestbundle/25884870#25884870) with FOSRestBundle using FosUserBundle. You just need to modify the code for only login with mail.

Comment: Concerning your second question, Token is a user authentication data. So I guess if someone steal it, he can have the access of the user.